# json_encode return undefined

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

My script returns undefined value from my json_encode php

index.php

```
<?php
    $returnThis['user'] = "Robin098";
    $returnThis['id'] = "08465";

    echo json_encode($returnThis);
?>
```

sample.html

```
<head>
    <script>
        function clickHere(){
            $.get("index.php", function(data) {
            alert(data.user);
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
       <body>
       <input type="button" onclick = "clickHere();" value="ClickHere!"/> 
       </body>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where does the `$aReturn` variable come from in your PHP script? You go from `$returnThis` to `$aReturn` with no explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method instead of `.get`, if you want your JSON to be parsed. Also, make sure that the jQuery library is correctly loaded.

```
    function clickHere(){
        $.getJSON("index.php", function(data) {
            alert(data.user);
        });
    }
```

Currently, you're using `$.get(url, function(data){...})`. In this context, `data` is a string containing the response from the server:

```
{"user":"Robin098","id":"80465"}
```

Using `alert(data)` inside the function will show this string.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're setting up `$returnThis`, but then returning `$aReturn`.  Don't you want:

```
$returnThis['user'] = "Robin098";
$returnThis['id'] = "08465";

echo json_encode($returnThis);
```

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan - in that case, it looks like Rob W's answer it what you want.  either .getJSON or $.ajax with dataType set to json

Comment: No, I just mistyped my code here, not the same with my actual code. You helped me. tnx.